# Speech SDK trowing error: Exception with an error code: 0xe (SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE)

Tags: python, linux, azure, azure-speech

I have a small script in python:

```
def listen(language):
speech_config.speech_recognition_language=language
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
print("Speak into your microphone.")
speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))
    return speech_recognition_result.text
```

This code is derived from the QuickStart SpeechSDK Tutorial found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=linux%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-python

It works perfectly under my MacOS Ventura 13.0 detecting speech. However, when I try it on my Linux Machine running Ubuntu 22.10 using the exact same hardware for audio detection it throws the following error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/fabian/Schreibtisch/Chatbot/gui.py", line 184, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: main(set_language,"doctor"),
  File "/home/fabian/Schreibtisch/Chatbot/ada_dialog_functions.py", line 233, in main
    gender_age=ask_age_gender(language,language_voice_id,language_country_id)
  File "/home/fabian/Schreibtisch/Chatbot/ada_dialog_functions.py", line 188, in ask_age_gender
    answer=listen(language_country_id)
  File "/home/fabian/Schreibtisch/Chatbot/ada_dialog_functions.py", line 15, in listen
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
  File "/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/speech.py", line 1004, in __init__
    _call_hr_fn(
  File "/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/interop.py", line 62, in _call_hr_fn
    _raise_if_failed(hr)
  File "/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/interop.py", line 55, in _raise_if_failed
    __try_get_error(_spx_handle(hr))
  File "/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/interop.py", line 50, in __try_get_error
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Exception with error code: 
[CALL STACK BEGIN]

/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.audio.sys.so(+0xe0f1) [0x7f53e240e0f1]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1c9cf8) [0x7f53e31c9cf8]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0xf4c35) [0x7f53e30f4c35]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x18251b) [0x7f53e318251b]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0xe7ad3) [0x7f53e30e7ad3]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1c9cf8) [0x7f53e31c9cf8]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0xf4c35) [0x7f53e30f4c35]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x180101) [0x7f53e3180101]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x18334f) [0x7f53e318334f]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1309e7) [0x7f53e31309e7]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1309e7) [0x7f53e31309e7]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x15aeb1) [0x7f53e315aeb1]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x134d3d) [0x7f53e3134d3d]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1dc61d) [0x7f53e31dc61d]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x130815) [0x7f53e3130815]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(+0x1f87f6) [0x7f53e31f87f6]
/home/fabian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(recognizer_create_speech_recognizer_from_config+0xf2) [0x7f53e30d121b]
[CALL STACK END]

Exception with an error code: 0xe (SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE)
```

I tried changing the microphone using the `device_name= "hw:CARD=U0x4b40x306,DEV=0` however this did not work either. Most of the solutions for this bug do not mention my combination of OS and Language, therefore are not really applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same error when I run the python script in linux machine.

[image]

> packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so(recognizer_create_speech_recognizer_from_config+0xf2)[0x7fd4507d121b]   [CALL STACK END]Exception with an error code: 0xe (SPXERR_MIC_NOT_AVAILABLE)

The above error occurs either the mic is not recognized or not detected by the speech recognition system.

In Linux check with **`arecord -l`** you can check the sound card you were using.

In my environment, I installed the  **`pulseaudio`** in the Linux machine, it worked for me.

**Command:**

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

**Console:**
[image]

After I installed pulseaudio, Now I tried with the same python script in my environment and it worked perfectly.

**Code:**

```
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def recognize_from_microphone():
    # This example requires environment variables named "SPEECH_KEY" and "SPEECH_REGION"
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"

    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    print("Speak into your microphone.")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

    if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")

recognize_from_microphone()
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Sound Input device (microphone) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working#:%7E:text=I%20used%20pavucontrol%2C%20as%20explained%20in%20this%20Ask,Port%2C%20select%20the%20correct%20microphone%20%28front%20or%20rear%29)
2. [pulseaudio - Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=Ubuntu%2020.0.4%20using%20Cinnamon%20%28no%20Gnome%2FKDE%29%20on%20Dell,Do%20microphone%20audio%20test%20on%20each%20available%20device)